# Cloning Bitbucket Repository Using `SSH` With Bash Script Linux

Tags: linux, bash, bitbucket, terraform

I'm trying to provision a `vm` via terraform.
I want to clone `Bitbucket` repository using `ssh` on `vm`.
I'm using this in to bash script file `git clone git@bitbucket.org:projectname-com/ansible.git`. But I got this error:

```
The authenticity of host  
'bitbucket.org(***.***.***.*)' can't be established.
```

1. I created `ssh` private/public key.
2. I created `Access key` on the bitbucket repository with the public key .

Please let me know how can authenticate to `bitbucket` via `ssh` in bash script and clone a repository?

Comment: The error is about the *host* key.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: It's not complaining about *your* keys. The host key identifies the remote server you are connecting to.